# Node stream: pull n lines, transform and continue

Tags: node.js, parsing, stream, transform, fs

In my NodeJS, I would like to read a big file, process it by fragment (by n lines), consume the data and then process the next n lines.

I've try to use several modules (fs, es-stream, node-etl for the main ones) by I couldn't manage to do what I want.

The best I've done (code is below) didn't wait for the transformation completion before processing new lines.

Here my snippet:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const es = require('event-stream');
const parse = require('csv-parse');
const stringify = require('csv-stringify');
const etl = require('etl');

exports.toDatabase = (file, done) => {

  // File contains six lines wit htwo values (example : aa:bb for the first line)
  let input = fs.createReadStream(todayTeamsFile);

  input
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(etl.collect(2))
    .pipe(es.map((data, nextMap) => {
      // I'd like to process all this code before continuing to read my stream
      let date = Date.now();
      console.log('map data ' + date);
      console.log(data);

      parse(data[0], {
        delimiter: ';'
      }, (err, output) => {
        console.log('Row done ' + date);
        // Treatment to do would be to insert in database the output
        console.log(output);
        console.log('------ ' + date);
        return nextMap();
      });

    }));

};
```

But the output show that the next map is launched before completion of the first call

```
TESTING !!
map data 1481824486765
[ 'aa;zz', 'bb;cc' ]
map data 1481824486771
[ 'dd;ee', 'ff;gg' ]
Row done 1481824486765
[ [ 'aa', 'zz' ] ]
------ 1481824486765
Row done 1481824486771
[ [ 'dd', 'ee' ] ]
------ 1481824486771
map data 1481824486785
[ 'hh;ii', '' ]
Row done 1481824486785
[ [ 'hh', 'ii' ] ]
------ 1481824486785
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you d like to re chunk the chunked stream, but here you go,

```
var through = require('through2');
var split = require('split')
var fs = require('fs')
var handler = (function(len) {
  var buff = [];
  var p = 0;
  return through.obj(function(chunk, enc, cb) {
    buff.push(chunk);
    p++;
    if(buff.length===len) {
      console.log('send--------------');
      this.push(buff);
      buff = [];
    }
    if (p>25) {
      this.emit('error', 'kill the stream')
    }
    cb();
  }, function (cb) {
    this.push(buff); // may be much larger than 4, it may need a logic to re split.
    buff = [];
    cb();
  });
})(4);

var origin = fs.createReadStream('tomate.csv');

origin
.pipe(split())
.pipe(handler)
.pipe(through.obj(function(chunk, enc, cb){
  console.log('process: %v', chunk);
  cb()
}));

handler.on('error', function () {
  origin.close();
  // still need o unpipe everything, use mississipi
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply !
The pause is done here but could you help me with details explaining your code ?
However this snippet  does a line-by-line and doest not send n lines at a times.
What do you mean by-rechunk the chunked stream ?
The idea here is to extract several lines (example 100 over 20000) for validating and doing bulk insert in a database. Stop reading if any insertion fails.

Comment: Please give me some questions i can try to uncover for you. For what you have explained of your problem, i d say instead of `buff.forEach(this.push.bind(this));` you could do `this.push(buff);`, and in the next stream handler, process the received Array of n items (build the sql, send it to the server, get the response, if any error => this.emit(error', err);), to keep the stream sync while doing the sql process, invoke stream.cb within sql.cb.

Comment: I forgot you need to use through.obj to pass in objects instead of string.

Comment: I've done some tests and reading of module throught and now I understand much more your snippet. To be sure, I'll try to explain it, please correct me if necessary : split make a chunk a single line of my file. Then the first through buffers by waiting for 4 lines to flush (this.push in 2nd function of through). And last through finishes by processing one line at a time. Why do you need a flag 'p', could this really happen ?

Comment: understanding is correct. Don t forget the flush function in through. p is just a token to reach 25 the emit an error and shows 1/ stream error handling (they do not propagate across handlers, each handlers must have its own listener) 2/ close and unpipe. To go further i strongly suggest to check https://github.com/maxogden/mississippi#pipe

Comment: Okay my test file was not 25 lines long, I've tested it. And I'm trying also missipi which will clearly avoid the manual unpiping I did in another readStream to writeStream function ! This is really what I needed, thanks !